# Dominion Seaside Treasure Map: do both copies activate?

Tags: dominion, dominion-seaside

The **Treasure Map** text says:

> Trash this and another copy of Treasure Map from your hand. If you do trash two Treasure Maps, gain 4 Gold cards, putting them on top of your deck.

If I manage to play both Treasure Cards as actions, do they both activate their full effects? That is: do I get 8 Gold cards?

Or, the moment I play the first, I have to trash the other one so preventing it for being played as an action?

Answer (score 8):

You play the first, performing its action of trashing itself and the second Treasure Map and gain 4 golds. You can't continue to play the second Treasure Map since it's no longer in your hand.

You also can't use Throne Room to gain more than 4 golds since the text states "**If** you do trash", and you can only trash a card once (I also tested on isotropic to make sure)

Comment: Thanks. That's was my impression too. Good catch about the Throne Room.

Comment: But, with three treasure maps and a throne room, you could throne the first and thrash the other two, gaining 8 golds?

Comment: @Konerak: No, because the "if" clause only triggers if you trash *two* Treasure Maps. The first time you play the original TM, you would be able to do so. The second time, though, the original TM has already been trashed; you would therefore trash the remaining TM from your hand but not gain the Golds, because you hadn't trashed two TMs during that play of the original TM.

Comment: There are other cards whose abilities aren't affected by Throne Room.  For example, Goons's +1 Victory token per card bought ability.

Comment: Now, if your hand is Village and 4x Treasure Map, then you can gain 8 Gold on top of your deck.

Comment: If your hand is Village and 4x Treasure Map, you're either doing something very wrong or very right.